# JS is working in console but doesn't work in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, liferay

I have this button which calls modal window with simple form.

```
<aui:button-row>
        <a style="float: left" onclick="ITD.robomarket.activateKeyModalWindowFunction(
        '${activateKeyURL}', '<%=LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "key-activating")%>', '400', '334')" class="btn btn-green"> </a>
</aui:button-row>
```

I want to close this modal window after submitting. I have already done this:

```
function closeModal () {
    var id = 'robomarket-activate-key-modal-window'
    var dialog = Liferay.Util.Window.getById(id);
    dialog.destroy();
}
```

And this function I call in .jsp:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        closeModal();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is this doesn't work BUT that modal window closes when I write this lines in console! What's the problem?

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" Dang, I hate those words, please explain what you expect to happend and what happens instead. Anyway, you're calling `closeModal` just after the DOM has been parsed, most likely the modal is not even shown at that time.

Comment: "I want to close this modal window after submitting", from where are you calling `closeModal()` when submitting?

Comment: @SajibKhan I'm calling `closeModal()` from jsp with that form in modal window.

Comment: @Teemu I expect to close my modal window after submitting the form.

Comment: Yes, but what happens instead? "It doesn't work" is not an answer to that question.

Comment: @Teemu When I try this code, I have an error with `dialog` variable: 

Uncaught TypeError: Liferay.Util.Window.getById is not a function

But that code works well in console.

Comment: OK, that sounds much better. Like I said in my first comment, the dialog doesn't exist at the time you're trying to close it. Make sure you're calling `closeModal` after you've enabled the modal.

Comment: maybe the required liferay js is not yet available: try to use `<aui:script use="liferay-util-window">` instead of just `<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call closeModal from the JSP where the modal was opened.
For exemple A.jsp has a link that open B.jsp in a modal dialog, then you want to close B.jsp when form is submitted

Here is a possible implementation :

In **A.jsp** :

```
    <portlet:renderURL var="popupUrl" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/B.jsp"/>
    </portlet:renderURL>

<aui:button href="${popupUrl}" useDialog="true" value="Open in popup" />
```

and at the bottom of A.jsp :

```
<aui:script>
Liferay.provide(window, 'closePopup', function(dialogId) {
        var A = AUI();
        var dialogId = A.one('div.dialog-iframe-modal').get("id");
        var dialog = Liferay.Util.Window.getById(dialogId);
        dialog.destroy();
});
</aui:script>
```

Then in **B.jsp**

You have to say to the opener to close the dialog, here is a possible implementation :

```
<portlet:actionURL name="/submitForm" var="submitFormURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="submitForm" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= submitFormURL %>" method="post" name="fm"  onSubmit='<%= "event.preventDefault(); " + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "submitForm();" %>'>
...the form

<aui:button name="submitForm" type="submit"/>

</aui:form>
```

And at the bottom of the **B.jsp** page :

```
<script>
    function <portlet:namespace/>submitForm(){
        AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A) {
            var url = '<%=submitFormURL.toString()%>';
            A.io.request(
                url,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    form: {id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm'},
                    on: {
                        success: function() {
                            Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('dialog');
                       }
                   }
               }
           );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Regards
Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

You are calling closeModal () method just after de DOM is ready. Wich mean you are asking to close even before the popUp is opened.

It is not clear what you do in your popUp. If is a partial submit, say an ajax call or similar, you need to call closeModal after you have got a response and treated the returned data.

Otherwise, if you are submiting a full submit, (a full reaload, navigation to a new page, you go through a whole new render phase) the modal window will dissapear with everi thing else in the currently renderes page.